# Is there a way to provide a predefined folder structure in SVN?

Tags: c++, eclipse, svn, code-organization

I am working on several C++ projects on my local computer. They all use some common libs and headers. The file structure is like this:

```
-bin
-lib
-include
-devel
   -project1
      -src
   -project2
      -src
-doc
```

I am using Eclipse IDE and i set all the relative paths. It compiles the executables to the bin folder and uses libs/includes within the structure. It works fine.

Now I need to import all the projects into an SVN repository so that different people can access and develop codes. 
And i wondering if there is a way to have this structure in the SVN server? So when someone checks out a project, he can just start working on it without organising the libs or headers. He will just check out, and all the relative linking will be done.

I am using Eclipse with subclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

why u don't use maven? with SVN or GIT it's very good...

Comment: Thanks. I am checking it. Do you suggest it for C++ projects too?

Comment: Things like this (standard project folder layout) are something that your build system should handle (such as Maven/Ant/etc.).  Look for terms like "convention over configuration" where if you follow the convention of directory layout and filenames, your project will build without fussing with tweaking any settings.